# Place order handler not working, redirects me to 404 error page, and the breakpoint doesn't get hit either, why?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult OnPostPlaceOrder()
{
    try
    {
        if (!_userManager.UserIsGuest())
        {
            int? customerID = _customerManager.GetCustomerId();
            if (customerID.HasValue)
            {
                var rentalOrder = new RentalOrder
                {
                    CustomerID = customerID.Value,
                    RentalStartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    RentalEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), 
                    TotalCost = _rentalOrderManager.CalculateTotalCost(Cart), 
                    Status = OrderStatus.Pending,
                    StartTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8), 
                    EndTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(18) 
                };

                int orderId = _rentalOrderManager.PlaceOrder(Cart, rentalOrder);

                return RedirectToPage("/OrderConfirmation", new { orderId });
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred in OnPostPlaceOrder method");
        return RedirectToPage("/Error");
    }
}

public IActionResult OnPostRemoveFromCart(int ItemID)
{
    _cartManager.RemoveItemFromCart(Cart, ItemID);
    return RedirectToPage("/Cart");
}
```

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="PlaceOrder">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

```
using BusinessLogicLayer;
using DataAccessLayer;
using SharedClassesLibrary;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddScoped<DataAccess>();
            services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IGuestManager, GuestManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IRentalItemRepository, RentalItemRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRentalItemManager, RentalItemManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IRentalOrderManager, RentalOrderManager>();
            services.AddScoped<RentalOrderManager>();
            services.AddScoped<ICustomerManager, CustomerManager>();

            services.AddScoped<ICartRepository, CartRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CartManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IRentalItemService, RentalItemService>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "CookieMonster";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300);
            });
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var userManager = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserManager>();
                var httpContext = context;
                var guestManager = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IGuestManager>(); 
                if (userManager.UserIsGuest() && !httpContext.Session.TryGetValue("GuestIdentifier", out byte[] sessionValue))
                {
                    var guestIdentifier = guestManager.GenerateNewGuestIdentifier();
                    httpContext.Session.Set("GuestIdentifier", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(guestIdentifier));
                }
                await next();
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the cshtml form code, and I expected successful redirection to the order confirmation page, so working functionality, or at least be able to debug the method, but it doesn't get hit either. Maybe I'm not noticing something really obvious. Help is highly appreciated. I've added the progam.cs code to it as well.

Comment: What project type you're using ?

Comment: Does it excute the `OnPostPlaceOrder()` ?

Comment: No, it doesn’t execute it, the breakpoint isn’t getting hit either there.

Comment: Is the  cshtml form code with the same  cshtml.cs ,the same razor page ? Could you share your code of Program.cs?

Comment: Yes. it's both the same cart razor page. I've shared the program code.

Comment: What's your structure of the razor page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Razor files under the `Pages` folder like:

[image]

Comment: They're all under the same folder, the other method on the page works fine.

Comment: @mimi  Do you set breakpoint at here ?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfZGl.png

Comment: Yes, I did it there and at other places of the same method to see whether somewhere it will work, but no. It just redirects me to the 404 error page, saying that the page doesn't work. This is the url: https://localhost:7121/Cart?handler=PlaceOrder, perhaps that will explain it more?

Comment: @mimi ,have a try to comment " app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var userManager = con..    await next();
            });"

Comment: Hi @mimi , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. The commenting out helped. I wasn't able to get back to you earlier; I had to make the customer process work for the cart functionality to test it without the guest part. It's working perfectly fine now! I'm new to this; definitely wouldn't have figured it out without your help.